# If condition Error on compiling - Specific question

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am trying to detect if the variables `f1` and `f2` have the letter v or b and then check if both words have the same length. I do not know why but when I run this code says that there are three errors on my if condition

```
    Scanner ask = new Scanner(System.in);
    String f1 = (ask.nextLine()).toLowerCase();
    String f2 = (ask.nextLine()).toLowerCase();
    boolean yes  = false;
    
    if((f1.indexOf("v") > -1 || f1.indexOf("b")) and (f2.indexOf("v") > -1 || f2.indexOf("b")) and (f1.length() == f2.length() )){
        yes = true;
    }
```

Error at compile

```
Solution.java:12: error: ')' expected
        if((wrd.indexOf("v") > -1 || wrd.indexOf("b")) and (wrd2.indexOf("v") > -1 || wrd2.indexOf("b")) and (wrd.length() == wrd2.length() )){
                                                      ^
Solution.java:12: error: ';' expected
        if((wrd.indexOf("v") > -1 || wrd.indexOf("b")) and (wrd2.indexOf("v") > -1 || wrd2.indexOf("b")) and (wrd.length() == wrd2.length() )){
                                                                                                        ^
Solution.java:12: error: ';' expected
        if((wrd.indexOf("v") > -1 || wrd.indexOf("b")) and (wrd2.indexOf("v") > -1 || wrd2.indexOf("b")) and (wrd.length() == wrd2.length() )){
^
3 errors
Exit Status

1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logical "and" operator in Java is `&&`, not the word `and`:

```
if ((f1.indexOf("v") > -1 || f1.indexOf("b")) && 
    (f2.indexOf("v") > -1 || f2.indexOf("b")) &&
    (f1.length() == f2.length())) {
```